# Question related to dream interpretation

Tags: tafseer, dream, beard

Assalamu alaikom,
what does it mean when you dream about the person you want to be with (you want to marry) without beard and mustache? (actually I just remember this part, it was a series of dreams..)
I also wanted to ask about another dream. I did salatu al2istikhara and asked god to guide me to keep or leave the person i want to be with and marry (he is christian trying to convert) and the same night I've dreamt of one of my eyes that was misplaced(still inside my eye orbit),but didnt hurt. And my mom came in order to fix it.
Is this ro2ya? if yes.. what does it mean?